# Transform values of a Pandas column with column index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

**EDIT: based on Quantam_something's answer below**

I need to transform the values of the column with specified column index, by subtracting the column mean and then returning the transformed values as a Pandas Series for the following dataframe.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(3,3)).add_prefix('col')

  col0 col1 col2
0   0   1    2
1   3   4    5
2   6   7    8
3   9   10   11
4   12  13   14
5   15  16   17
6   18  19   20
7   21  22   23
```

I have this so far. Can someone help me with the subtraction part?

```
def transform(colIndex)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(3,3)).add_prefix('col')
    df.iloc[,:colIndex].mean()
transform(3)
```

expected dataframe

```
 col0 col1  col2
0   0   1    -10.5
1   3   4    -7.5
2   6   7    -4.5
3   9   10   -1.5
4   12  13   1.5
5   15  16   4.5
6   18  19   7.5
7   21  22   10.5
```

Comment: `df['col2'].sub(df['col2'].mean())`?

Comment: Seems like `d['col2'] = d['col2'] - d['col2'].mean()` would work no? As an aside, `arange` 25 won't reshape into `(3, 3)`

Comment: can you please post the expected ending df?

Comment: thanks, Henry but I need to used column index to refer to the column

Comment: @rhug123 done!!

Comment: Okay `iloc` works the just the same `d.iloc[:, 3] = d.iloc[:, 3] - d.iloc[:, 3].mean()` also still `arange` 24 will not reshape to `(3,3)` arange should be `9` if the shape is `3x3` but then `colIndex` `3` would be out of bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

First of all, your code won't work because in python the index starts at `0` and not at `1`, so your `iloc` command won't work.

Then, I think you can simply do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(8,3)).add_prefix('col')
df.iloc[:,2] = df['col2'] - df['col2'].mean()
# Or more simply:  df['col2'] = df['col2'] - df['col2'].mean()
# or               df['col2'] = df['col2'].sub(df['col2'].mean())
```

OLDER ANSWER:

I am not 100% sure that I understand your question correctly. But I think this does what you want

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(8,3)).add_prefix('col')
d['col2'] - d['col2'].mean()
```

So, you are subtracting the mean value of col2 to each and every element of col2.

Also, your `np.arange(25).reshape(3,3)` is incorrect as you cannot arrange 25 numbers in a 3x3 matrix